# Using gRPC in client that must block on other fds - how?

Tags: linux, sockets, grpc, rpc, epoll

I have a C++ client binary that uses epoll() to block on various OS descriptors - for file I/O, socket I/O, OS timers; and now it also needs to be a gRPC client (including streaming replies).

Reading answers to related questions across the web (e.g. about servers) it appears that there is no easy way from C/C++ to ask gRPC to give an fd that can be incorporated into the existing epoll set and then trigger gRPC to do the read & processing for the incoming response.  Is that correct?

Alternatively, is the ***reverse*** possible: to use files, socket and timers via the gRPC core iomgr framework that are otherwise unrelated to the gRPC service? (for reading local files, communicating with external network equipment and managing the client's internal high-frequency timer needs.

The client in question is a single thread with RT priority (on an embedded (soft) real-time system using the PREEMPT RT).  Given that gRPC creates other threads, could that be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible today, but it will be in the future once we finish the [EventEngine](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/pull/245) effort.  Once ready, that will allow you to inject your own event loop into gRPC.  However, that probably won't be ready for public use until sometime next year.

For now, the only suggestion I can offer is that if you're using an insecure channel and don't need any name resolution or load balancing functionality, you may be able to use [`CreateInsecureChannelFromFd()`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/5ac68916dfb6c8ab1a773a911bd64e958f71b913/include/grpcpp/create_channel_posix.h#L37) to do the reverse (provide your own fd to use as a gRPC connection).